# Static (no slider) chart (Google Charts or otherwise) with single axis?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I need to show a range of values as a chart resembling the one below:

[image: chart with single axis]

The idea is that there is a minimum value and a maximum value. The value I’m trying to show will be a range probably somewhere in between.

I was going to use Google Charts, and their [Bar Chart (Image)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagebarchart) is almost what I want, but axis-wise **it shows both `x` and `y`,** and I seem to want only `x`, or maybe `y`. (In the words of the late Mark Pilgrim, “I am not explaining this well.”)

Can anyone show me how I might do this, either with this Google Bar Chart (or another Google Chart) or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with (this uses the Bar Chart Image — described above — from the Google Charts API, but does not use the labels from the chart):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["imagebarchart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        //Here we display a range from 10 million (10000000)
        //to 20 million (20000000), using a dummy value set
        //to 1 less than the low point of our range (in this
        //case, 9999999) and with the same color as the
        //chart's background. The dummy value will be stacked
        //on top of the value we want to show and blank out
        //the chart from 0 to where our range begins.

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['', ''],
            [9999999, 20000000]
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ImageBarChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
        chart.draw(data, {showValueLabels: false, backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',  width: 1000, height: 70, min: 100000, max: 50000000, colors: ['#f5f5f5', '#008000']});
    }
</script>
```

(`chart_div` is the div to be replaced by the chart when the page loads; this code is based on the example from [the chart docs](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagebarchart?hl=en).)

Obviously this particular bar chart isn’t meant to be used in this way, but it was the closest that I could find to what I wanted. I hope that this helps somebody with the same problem.